# SFML loadFromFile not working on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, fonts, sfml

This is a re-upload since my last question lost interest, sorry...

I've been trying to develop a cross-platform application for Windows and Linux using SFML. Everything's been going fine so far, except that the Windows version cannot seem to load fonts. I have no issues under Linux however. I did my research and made sure the file was in place, according to where I was executing from, but sf::Font::loadFromFile still returns false.

Here's the code:

```
sf::Font _font;
sf::Text _text;

if (!(_font.loadFromFile("resources/fonts/arial.ttf")))
{
    std::cerr << "Error loading font '" + font + "'" << std::endl;
    return;
}
_text.setFont(_font);
```

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using SFML 2.3, linking statically.

Update: the loadFromFile methods doesn't work either for textures. I can check programmatically that the files are in place, and opening them with ifstreams works fine, but SFML cannot seem to access them.

Comment: Don't re-post questions. Go back to your previous one and edit it to add more information. Editing posts bumps them back on the front page.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I am, but it shouldn't be an issue as I check the file is there programmatically. Also, using absolute file paths doesn't solve the issue.
I should also note that the Visual Studio solution is generated using CMake